# Closing application using FormClosing()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What I'm trying to do is when I press X button on my application, that application will delete some files and then it will close it self. Unfortunately I can't get it to work without asking me questions before quitting application it self.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    System.IO.Directory.Delete(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp + "/REACH_DT", True)

    Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, 
     e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing     
     Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?",
         "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)         
         Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes         
         Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No             
             e.Cancel = True                  
     End Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: what questions is it asking and what is `it` the app or the OS?  and why all the extra VB tags?  vb.net <> vb6 <>vbscript

Comment: It works with this code

`Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            e.Cancel = True 
                End Select
End Sub`

Comment: So your problem is that a message box pops up when you call `MessageBox.Show(...)`?

Comment: easy answer...it asking some questions because you have code which asks some questions.  it is the 21st century and people know what closing an app does.  there really is no readon to ask "Are you sure" unless there is unsaved data.  Give you users a little credit.

Comment: Agreed.  The code appears to be doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

I think, although its not clear from your question, that you're getting the question asked twice (or more) maybe?

In which case, remove the `Close()` call. This is in the close event, and attempts to close the form once again.

The form will automatically close when the event is processing done, as long as `e.Cancel` is not true.